# Question on limsup of sets (Basic)

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

Let $A_n$ and $B_n$ be sequence of sets. Suppose that, for all sufficiently large $n$, $A_n\subseteq B_n$.

Does it imply $\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}A_n\subseteq \lim\sup_{n\to\infty}B_n$?

**Sketch of my thoughts**

By definition $\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}A_n=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k:= \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty C_n$, where $C_n=\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k$ is a decreasing sequence. Similarly, we can write $\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}B_n:=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty D_n$, with $D_n$ decreasing.

By our hypothesis, there is some $n_0$ such that $C_n\subseteq D_n$ for all $n>n_0$. Since both sequences are decreasing, $\bigcap_{n=1}^{n_0} C_n \cap \bigcap_{n=n_0+1}^{\infty} C_n=\bigcap_{n=n_0+1}^{\infty} C_n$. The same holds for $D_n$. If nothing is wrong, we have
$$\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}A_n=\bigcap_{n=n_0+1}^{\infty} C_n\subseteq \bigcap_{n=n_0+1}^{\infty} D_n=\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}B_n.$$

Comment: Do you know that $x\in\limsup_nA_n$ if and only if $\{n:x\in A_n\}$ is infinite?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So, the set $\lim\sup_n A_n$  is what remains  when $n$ is large, precisely, when $n$ is infinite. Following this reasoning, the answer should be YES.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I believe my inefficient sketch went along this line.

Comment: A useful way to think about $\limsup_nA_n$ and $\liminf_nA_n$ is that the former is the set of points that are in infinitely many of the sets $A_n$, while the latter is the set of points that are in all of the $A_n$ from some point on. \\ You’ve worked a bit harder than necessary: if $A_n\subseteq B_n$ for all $n\ge n_0$, then $C_n\subseteq D_n$ for all $n\ge n_0$, so $\bigcap_{n\ge n_0}C_n\subseteq\bigcap_{n\ge n_0}D_n$. And since the sets $C_n$ and $D_n$ are decreasing, $$\bigcap_nC_n=\bigcap_{n\ge n_0}=\bigcap_{n\ge n_0}D_n=\bigcap_nD_n\;,$$ and you’re done. No need for $n_0+1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you. I agree.

Comment: You’re welcome.